# Creating an alternative login page other than /user/login

Tags: 7, forms, users

I have managed to do this in Drupal 7 with the following code:

```
function my_special_paths_menu() {

    $items['authenticate'] = array(
        'title' => 'Log in',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('user_login'),   
        'access callback' => 'user_is_anonymous',   
      );
     return $items;
    }
```

My question, is this code complete or is it missing some configuration in the menu item array? Is the code safe the way it is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your code is complete, and is as safe as the default login form.

However, do bear in mind that if you want to replace the `/user/login` form, you will need to think about all scenarios in which users might end up there (e.g. `[site:login-url]` token, other modules, etc.) and handle them appropriately via redirects or access denied response (e.g. if you will be the only registered user on the site).

Here are the basics:

#### Redirecting

If you want to redirect users from `/user/login` to `/authenticate` for whatever reason, you will either need to use the [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module, or implement `hook_menu_alter()` in your custom module:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/login']['page callback'] = 'drupal_goto';
  $items['user/login']['page arguments'] = 'authenticate';
}
```

#### Replacing

If you want to make `/user/login` inaccessible to all other users, you can simply disable that path by again implementing the `hook_menu_alter()` in your custom module:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/login']['access callback'] = FALSE;
}
```

However, do bear in mind that you will have to test everything thoroughly and make sure that you have no modules that depend on the system `/user/login`, as well as that there are no workflows that will be affected (e.g. `[site:login-url]` tokens).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Rename Admin Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/rename_admin_paths) on one of my sites to have another URL instead of /user/... and /admin/... Works great, right out of the box.